# Is there a way to speed up this multi-table query with indices?

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, indexing, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to get all tags that belong to all of a user's conversations (a user has many conversations via a `ConversationUserPair` join) - but the query is taking on average 2,000ms.

```
SELECT "tags"."tag_text_downcased"
FROM "tags"
INNER JOIN "conversations" ON "tags"."conversation_id" = "conversations"."id"
INNER JOIN "conversation_user_pairs" ON "conversations"."id" = "conversation_user_pairs"."conversation_id"
WHERE "conversation_user_pairs"."user_id" = ?
AND "conversation_user_pairs"."conversation_status" = ?
AND ("tags"."user_id" = ?);
```

When I run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` in the psql console, this is the response I get:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT "tags"."tag_text_downcased" FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "conversations" ON "tags"."conversation_id" = "conversations"."id" INNER JOIN "conversation_user_pairs" ON "conversations"."id" = "conversation_user_pairs"."conversation_id" WHERE "conversation_user_pairs"."user_id" = '459' AND "conversation_user_pairs"."conversation_status" = 'active' AND ("tags"."user_id" = '459');

Nested Loop  (cost=462.87..486.65 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.457..1.886 rows=40 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (tags.conversation_id = conversations.id)
   ->  Merge Join  (cost=462.78..482.97 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.401..1.334 rows=40 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: (tags.conversation_id = conversation_user_pairs.conversation_id)
         ->  Sort  (cost=462.70..462.83 rows=259 width=15) (actual time=0.332..0.337 rows=40 loops=1)
               Sort Key: tags.conversation_id
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tags  (cost=4.49..460.62 rows=259 width=15) (actual time=0.152..0.295 rows=40 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (user_id = 459)
                     Heap Blocks: exact=23
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_tags_on_user_id_and_conversation_id  (cost=0.00..4.47 rows=259 width=0) (actual time=0.105..0.105 rows=40 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (user_id = 459)
         ->  Index Only Scan using by_user_and_conversation_and_status on conversation_user_pairs  (cost=0.08..20.02 rows=522 width=4) (actual time=0.066..0.956 rows=390 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((user_id = 459) AND (conversation_status = 'active'::text))
               Heap Fetches: 134
   ->  Index Only Scan using index_conversations_on_id on conversations  (cost=0.08..3.68 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=40)
         Index Cond: (id = conversation_user_pairs.conversation_id)
         Heap Fetches: 40
```

I think I have proper indexes on the three separate tables in question. I have:

```
add_index "tags", ["conversation_id", "user_id", "tag_text_downcased"], name: "find_tag_text_downcased_tags"
add_index "tags", ["conversation_id", "user_id"], name: "index_conversation_first_tags"
add_index "tags", ["user_id", "conversation_id"], name: "index_tags_on_user_id_and_conversation_id"

add_index "conversation_user_pairs", ["user_id", "conversation_id", "conversation_status"], name: "by_user_and_conversation_and_status"

add_index "conversations", ["id"], name: "index_conversations_on_id"
```

Is there nothing to be done here to speed up the query, as it looks like it's using an index from each of the tables? Or is there a way to have a multi-table index?

Comment: Your `EXPLAIN` shows times in milliseconds, not seconds. The query took less than 2 milliseconds to execute. The slowest part is the index only scan on `conversation_user_pairs`, taking ~1 millisecond, probably because of 134 heap fetches (table data): https://explain.depesz.com/s/7DYn

Comment: Find a guideline for instrumental information in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: @Ancoron thanks for the link, very helpful. Yes, this particular query ran quickly but my server tooling is showing this same query taking over 4,000ms at times.

Answer (score 0):

I'm filling in with educated guesses where information is missing ...

#### Query

The query you display is not ideal for your declared objective:

> I'm trying to get all tags that belong to all of a user's conversations

And by "all" you mean "any" I assume.

Also assuming that referential integrity is enforced with foreign key constraints. Then we can cut out the middleman `conversations`. Joining to it adds nothing but cost.

The way you have it, the query can return the same tags multiple times. Assuming you want unique tags, it's enough to assert that any matching rows in `conversation_user_pairs` *exist*. An [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join is typically the best way to do that:

```
SELECT t.tag_text_downcased
FROM   tags t
WHERE  t.user_id = 459  -- assuming it's a numeric data type
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT
   FROM   conversation_user_pairs cu
   WHERE  cu.user_id         = t.user_id
   AND    cu.conversation_id = t.conversation_id
   AND    cu.conversation_status = 'active'
   );
```

#### Indexes

Your index `find_tag_text_downcased_tags` on `tags` is perfect.
And `by_user_and_conversation_and_status` is also good for it. If many rows are not "active", while you are mostly interested in the active ones, a partial index can be even better:

```
CREATE INDEX ON conversation_user_pairs (user_id, conversation_id)
WHERE conversation_status = 'active';
```

You don't need the other indexes here. And since you have these two:

```
add_index "tags", ["conversation_id", "user_id", "tag_text_downcased"], name: "find_tag_text_downcased_tags"
add_index "tags", ["user_id", "conversation_id"], name: "index_tags_on_user_id_and_conversation_id"
```

... it's typically not useful to keep this one, too:

```
add_index "tags", ["conversation_id", "user_id"], name: "index_conversation_first_tags"
```

You can probably drop it. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Aside: If `conversation_status` only has 'active' and 'dead' or similar, make it a `boolean` column. Smaller & cheaper than `text`.

Comment: You're exactly right thinking about it that `conversations` is not necessary here, since we already have `conversation_id` through `conversation_user_pairs`. It is true that we want "any" (not "all") tags, but `tags.tag_text_downcased` is actually a unique column and so "any" and "all" are essentially interchangeable if I'm understanding the implications. I have never created a partial index! I will read up on that and give it a try as well. Thank you.

Comment: `tags.tag_text_downcased` may be "unique" (how exactly? table definition is missing), but joining to `conversation_user_pairs` would typically multiply rows. (Looks like a 1:n relationship.) Be that as it may, `EXISTS` is right in any case - and typically fastest.